# How to show html codes inside TextView or something else on Android?

Tags: android, html, textview

How can I show html source as rendered in TextView or something else?
I tried this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    String s = "<img src=\"http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/146278/purple-lotus-lovely-dew.jpg\"/>";
    Spanned sp = new SpannableString(s);

    tv.setText(Html.toHtml(sp));
}
```

But I got:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML support in a TextView is pretty limited, but here is an example of some of the things you can do:

https://github.com/brianjolly/TextFun

The key is escaping the opening bracket in your strings.xml

```
<string name="fun_text">I like &lt;font color=\'0x00b0f1\'>BLUE!&lt;/font> and &lt;b> Bold&lt;/b> and &lt;i> italic&lt;/i> and &lt;u> underline&lt;/u></string>
```

And then resetting the text like so:

```
String styledText = tv.getText().toString();
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

The beauty of open source is you can see what Html.fromHtml() supports in the android source here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java

If you're looking to do something more advanced take a look at [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html is very nice tutorial. Thank you for your answer...

Comment: @Brian why doesn't my string show correct color? it's <string name="formatting">&lt;div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 25px; font-size: 17px;">&lt;p>&lt;strong>&lt;span style="color: #ff0000;">API docs&lt;/span>&lt;/strong>&lt;/p>&lt;/div></string>.