# Android - write "<", ">" or "&" instead of &lt, &gt and &amp

Tags: android, keyboard

i have made and android chat application using smack. my problem is when i write "<", ">" or "&" in group chat it writes "&lt", "&gt" and &amp instead of "<", ">" and "&". but in one-to-one chat it works fine and does not write "&lt", &gt or &amp. how can i solve this problem? I have no idea what is causing this.

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what smack is

Comment: Maybe this one: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/

Comment: Smack is an Open Source XMPP (Jabber) client library for instant messaging and presence. but my problem seems to be more of android or android keyboard but still cant guess what is the real cause

Comment: @FallakAsad see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7086349/1338846

Answer (score 0):

Use `&gt;` for greater than symbol and `&lt;` for less than symbol, so here you need to replace like:

```
<string name="your_name">&lt;Your Name&gt;</string>
```

The Android string.xml file is just a regular XML file, so you can use the XML escape characters such as:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```